# How to install Snow Leopard virtual machine on new iMac with Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I got a 2013 iMac with Mountain Lion (10.8.5 now) and incompatible with Snow Leopard. I need SL anyway.

Giving up all my old applications and buying new ones is not acceptable. First, this is not my way of thinking and, second, some cannot be replaced.

Many posts say that you can use Snow Leopard with VirtualBox but I could not find anywhere the "how to" (in this particular configuration).

For instance, I followed these 2 protocols, almost similar:

http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-in-virtualbox-on-windows/

http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/02/snow-leopard-virtualbox.html

but they use Windows as host system and something is not working (for me) with Mountain Lion.

I made many attempts, with VirtualBox 4.2.18, using pretty much everything: Snow Leopard DVD, SL Server DVD, a `.dmg` of both. I've also got Combo 10.6.8 updates for both (but I'm not sure if it can be used before installing). With another MacBook, I managed to install a SLS on external hard drive and update to 10.6.8. Was unable to use it anyway.

Inevitably, I ended up with the message:

> FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.

I have no idea of what support to use and even, probably  important, if it should be set on Primary or Secondary Master? (in Settings / Storage)

Is it possible at all?

Would it work better with VMware Fusion? Anybody successful?

Comment: Have you tried this one - http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/17/install-run-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-in-virtual-machine-on-lion/ ? It talks about a Mac OS X Snow Leopard VM on OS X Lion, but the process should be the same for OS X Mountain Lion too.

Comment: In VirtualBox, after creating the VM, have you registered the dmg file in the boot sequence? Of course you will get "no bootable medium found" if you haven't registered it; VirtualBox does not detect bootable volumes (and there is no way to detect them actually). You need to go to "Settings-->Storage", click on the disk plus icon, and choose your dmg. If you already have the dmg in your sequence but got the error, it means your dmg is wrong. I use VirtualBox with Ubuntu rather than OS X but there is no reason it can't work with SL.

Comment: By the way, the most recent version of VirtualBox is 4.3.2 and you can find it [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). In the newer version you should be prompted for boot volume if you did not register it. I don't remember whether there were such prompts in 4.2.18.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the last lines. Most of the time you just add the dmg, and don't need to adjust the settings (primary/secondary master, etc.). I don't understand what you mean by "what support to use." I think your best bet is to download the newest version of VirtualBox, follow the boot prompt and totally forget about the settings you don't understand. But the most important thing is to get the right SL install dmg.

Comment: Thanks for your help and comments.
Your link sends to a method which just mentions "Select the Snow Leopard DVD or dmg or etc..."
But how ? This is the tough part in VirtualBox (even worse with 4.3.2). Should you use SATA controler, create IDE, something else?
By support, i mean DVD or dmg (I'm unable to select DVD and I cannot make it work with dmg)? SL system or server (this is not an issue from VirtualBox but I cannot find the right information on the web)?

Answer (score 1):

To attach the DVD image, you need to first convert it from dmg format to iso using DiskUtility.
Then in the Virtualbox settings go to the storage settings and click on the little DVD icon next to where the popup menu with Sata1 is and select the iso image.

That said, I haven't been able to get it to boot successfully - it shows the apple logo but then gets stuck at the spinning wheel...